# Open a new listbox from another listbox .net asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am very new to asp .net development and c#. I have created two list boxes using  and namned them. My first list box will have a number of ListItems. I would like that when i press one item on my listbox, my other listbox will load some specific items. Let's say that my first listbox contains a number of cars. When i click on one car my other listbox will show all the components of that car i picked. I appriciate all the help i can get.

Comment: use ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event

Comment: Tag as ASP.NET if that is what you are using

Answer (score 0):

Assume this example for Categories and items (same as Car and Components)

I created a winform with two list boxes listbox1 and listbox2 and this is what my Form1.cs looks like:

```
namespace WinFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Category> categories;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            categories = new List<Category>();

            var categoryOne = new Category { Name = "Category 1"} ;
            categoryOne.Items.Add( new CategoryItem { Name = "Item 1"} );

            var categoryTwo = new Category { Name = "Category 2" };
            categoryTwo.Items.Add( new CategoryItem { Name = "Item 2" } );

            categories.Add( categoryOne );
            categories.Add( categoryTwo );
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            categoryBindingSource.DataSource = categories;
        }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<CategoryItem> Items { get; private set; }

        public Category()
        {
            Items = new List<CategoryItem>();
        }
    }

    public class CategoryItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is the InitializeComponent() code

```
this.listBox1.DataSource = this.categoryBindingSource;
        this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 24);
        this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
        this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(242, 238);
        this.listBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.listBox1.ValueMember = "Items";

        this.categoryBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Category);

        this.listBox2.DataSource = this.itemsBindingSource;
        this.listBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(286, 24);
        this.listBox2.Name = "listBox2";
        this.listBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(276, 238);
        this.listBox2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.listBox2.ValueMember = "Name";

        this.itemsBindingSource.DataMember = "Items";
        this.itemsBindingSource.DataSource = this.categoryBindingSource;
```

Comment: In his first sentence OP said: "I am very new to **asp .net** development and c#" Nice winforms example, but... :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a very broad question.
But, here's something to get you started.

markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <p>
        <asp:ListBox runat="server" id="lbCars" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbCars_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px" Height="100px" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:ListBox runat="server" id="lbParts"  Width="200px" Height="100px"></asp:ListBox>
    </p> 
</asp:Content>
```

and code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadCarsList();

            }
        }


        protected void lbCars_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            //this will be executed when selected item in list of cars is changes
            //load parts
            LoadPartsList(this.lbCars.SelectedValue);
        }

        protected void LoadCarsList()
        {
            //here is the place to load cars list from database.
            //for this example, cars are hard-coded
            this.lbCars.Items.Clear();
            this.lbCars.Items.Add(new ListItem("Peugeot", "1"));
            this.lbCars.Items.Add(new ListItem("VW", "2"));
            this.lbCars.Items.Add(new ListItem("Ford", "3"));
            this.lbCars.Items.Add(new ListItem("Fiat", "4"));
        }

        protected void LoadPartsList(string carId)
        {
            //this will be called when you s
            this.lbParts.Items.Clear();

            this.lbParts.Items.Add("part one for car " + carId);
            this.lbParts.Items.Add("part two for car " + carId);
            this.lbParts.Items.Add("part three for car " + carId);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but i get a nullpointerexeption on the line LoadPartsList(this.lbCars.SelectedValue); i can't find the error, any tips?

Comment: Looks like `lbCars.SelectedValue` is `null`. Add `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lbCars.SelectedValues))` before `LoadPartsList(this.lbCars.SelectedValue);`